# For Function keeps looping

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ethers.js

My code keeps looping all the IDs for this part of my code while i only want it to loop through the IDs of pictures the account owns, let's say someone owns IDs 1 - 4 the code now loops infinitely through those numbers and keeps looping through them and refreshing the pictures without giving id 1, then 2 etc. :

```
function getMeta() {
    let nfts = []
    for(let i = 0; i < elfBalance; i++) {
        nftContract.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(currentAccount, i).then((result:string)=>{setId(result.toString())})
        nfts.push(<img id={tokenIds} width="128" height="128" alt='' src={"https://opensea.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmXuUzMCSybPdcySbn4h7F11hYAY3QkEQKeaDHtKPdZ38t/"+tokenIds+".png"} />)
      }
    return (
      <div>
        {nfts}
      </div>
    )
    
    }
```

my entire code:

```
import { ethers, utils , BigNumber} from "ethers";
import abi from '../web3/abi.json';
import './Inventory.css';
import { Button2 } from '../Button';
import Loadpics from './loadpics';

const contractAddress = "0x89e0A37218333b6dFd6785E33f0AFd913BD8406d"
const provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
const nftContract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi , provider)



export default function Inventory() {

    const [currentAccount, setCurrentAccount] = useState('')
    const [elfBalance, setBalance] = useState('')
    const [tokenIds, setId] = useState('')

    const onClickConnect = () => {
      if(!window.ethereum) {
        console.log("please install MetaMask")
        return
      }
      provider.send("eth_requestAccounts", [])
      .then((accounts)=>{
        if(accounts.length>0) setCurrentAccount(accounts[0])
        console.log(accounts[0])
      })
      .catch((e)=>console.log(e))
    }
  
    const onClickDisconnect = () => {
      console.log("onClickDisConnect")
      setCurrentAccount(undefined)
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
      if(!currentAccount || !ethers.utils.isAddress(currentAccount)) return
      //client side code
      if(!window.ethereum) return
      nftContract.balanceOf(currentAccount).then((result:string)=>{
        console.log(result)
        setBalance(result.toString())
      })
      

    },[currentAccount])

    function getMeta() {
        let nfts = []
        for(let i = 0; i < elfBalance; i++) {
            nftContract.tokenOfOwnerByIndex(currentAccount, i).then((result:string)=>{setId(result.toString())})
            nfts.push(<img id={tokenIds} width="128" height="128" alt='' src={"https://opensea.mypinata.cloud/ipfs/QmXuUzMCSybPdcySbn4h7F11hYAY3QkEQKeaDHtKPdZ38t/"+tokenIds+".png"} />)
          }
        return (
          <div>
            {nfts}
          </div>
        )
        
        }
            
  
    function renderMetamask() {
      if (!currentAccount || !ethers.utils.isAddress(currentAccount)) {
        return (
          <Button2 buttonStyle='btn--black' buttonSize='btn--small' className='connect-wallet' onClick={onClickConnect}>Connect Wallet</Button2>
        )
      } else {

        return(
          <div>
          {getMeta()}
          </div>
        )
      
    }
  }
  
    return(
    <div>
      {renderMetamask()}
    </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `i` in the extraneous loops? Could `i` or `elfBalance` be increasing as you're looping?

Comment: No its a fixed number, for example if someone owns 4 elves in the game, elfBalance would be 4 for that person

Comment: What is the value of `i` in the extraneous loops?

Comment: Your useeffect rerenders ,will probably give a warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that what is happening here is because of the setId being called inside of the getMeta() function.

The call to setId is triggering a re-render, which ends up in getMeta() being called again, which calls setId again, triggering another render and causing this loop.

Something here probably needs to occur in a useEffect hook or something similar.

Comment: This was the issue indeed, fixed it by using web3.js instead of ethers.js